# How to load javascript script into WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to insert the following script https://github.com/akella/fake3d into my Wordpress website but i'm struggling to make it works..

I added the source code to my child theme and enqueued the .js to wp in the function.php like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Fake3DEffect_load' );
function Fake3DEffect_load(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'Fake3DEffect_src', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/Fake3DEffect/js/src.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'Fake3DEffect_app', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/Fake3DEffect/js/app.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'Fake3DEffect_gyronorm', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/Fake3DEffect/js/lib/gyronorm.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

but on console log i get this error on line 1:

```
import fragment from './shaders/fragment.glsl'; <--- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

It looks like it won't import the .glsl (shaders) files from app.js and src.js.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 3 scripts only 1.

See [the examples](https://github.com/akella/fake3d/blob/master/index.html)

They have a div with the id of 'gl' and a bunch of parameters

```
            <div 
                id="gl" 
                data-imageOriginal="img/lady.jpg" 
                data-imageDepth="img/lady-map.jpg" 
                data-horizontalThreshold="35" 
                data-verticalThreshold="15">
            </div>
```

and at the end they just include one script

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

The script tag needs to appear at the bottom of the page's HTML not the top in order to work.